# Systemd service unit file as user

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, systemd

I'm new to the concept of systemd unit files in Centos 7 but need to start up the MATLAB license manager at boot. MATLAB doesn't offer a specific solution on how to do this, and the following seems to work but asks for a password when typing `systemctl start license-manager` and `systemctl stop license-manager`. Is that expected?

Note this does need to run as a specific user and not as root.

Here is my `/etc/systemd/system/license-manager.service`file:

```
[Unit]
Description=MATLAB FlexLM license manager

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/etc/lmstart
ExecStop=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/etc/lmdown
KillMode=none
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=90
User=lmlicenseuser

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Crontab

```
bash$ crontab -e
```

then add the following line

```
@reboot /usr/local/MATLAB/R201Xx/etc/lmstart
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: That should work, thanks for the suggestion! Odd it's not on MATLAB's site.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally it is always expected for non-root users to be asked for a password when running commands as other users, yes.

However, because you have specified that it is a dependency of `multi-user.target`, it should always be started automatically whenever you reboot in future, so you shouldn't need to enter the password in future.

If for some reason you do still need to control it manually in future, you can use `sudo` and edit `/etc/sudoers` to allow those two particular commands to be run without a password, using `NOPASSWD`.

Comment: Thanks Robin, but even as user lmlicenseuser I get prompted for a password. Would it be more desirable to change its dependency to default.target?